# How to install pandas and dependencies offline

Tags: c++, windows, pandas, server

everyone!

I've been trying to install pandas on as windows server 2012 machine but I need to do this offline. 
I've been facing some errors. I tried install the whl file and tried python setup.py install, but both comes without dependencies like the C extension. 
[C extension hashtable not built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7QZQ.png)

When I try to build_ext I get another error, Telling me to get the C++ 9.0 from microsoft distributor I see taht there's not a version for the Windows server 2012 :/

I'm trying to see another way of getting those dependencies offline but if teh c++ is really needed 
[Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzErI.png)

I would like to know if someone know a version for the operational systenm I'm using, please

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the anaconda distribution of Python? 
https://www.anaconda.com/download/

It comes with Pandas. 
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/#installing-anaconda-on-a-non-networked-machine-air-gap

Comment: I use ArcGIS and we had situations where anaconda were interfering on functionalities of ArcGIS